# Epson User-Defined Character Printing

Tags: printing, epson, escpos

I just want to Add Rupee Symbol with the help of the following:

> [Name] Define user-defined characters
>
> [Format] ASCII ESC & y c1 c2 [x1 d1 ... d(y × x1)] ... [xk d1 ... d(y
>   × xk)]
>
> Hex 1B 26 y c1 c2 [x1 d1 ... d(y × x1)] ... [xk d1 ... d(y × xk)]
>
> Decimal 27 38 y c1 c2 [x1 d1 ... d(y × x1)] ... [xk d1 ... d(y × xk)]

Can any one guide me and give me sample code how can I define and use the User Defined Char in thermal Printer using escape sequences?

What I have tried:

I am unable to use, but I tried to convert bitmap images to string and I concatenated in place of x1d1....xkd1 but not printing user-defined char any more.

Comment: This is not a complete answer to your question, but in [this thread](https://github.com/python-escpos/python-escpos/issues/33) there is a description on how to load custom fonts into a capable printer.